# System call to plot a point in c( linux)

Tags: c, linux, graphics

I am new to Linux system calls.My question is do we have a system call in Linux to plot points on screen.I googled it but could not find any simple explanation for it. I want to write a simple C program in Linux that directly plot a point on screen without the help of a C graphics library.

If there is no such system call how can I create my own system call to plot point on screen?

Comment: Why does it need to be a system call?  How about writing to `/dev/fbX`  - does that count?

Answer (score 3):

The lowest level hardware independent graphics interface on linux is the [framebuffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_framebuffer).  This is manipulated by writing to a device node (generally `/dev/fb0`) which is the equivalent of a system call, since it is a means of sending requests to the kernel.  So this does not require any libraries.

A common approach seems to be to `mmap()` a chunk of user space memory representing the screen to `/dev/fb0` and then manipulating that.  There are some `ioctl()` calls to get information about the framebuffer display.  A good starting place for information would be the docs in the kernel source -- `src/Documentation/fb` is a whole directory, see e.g. "framebuffer.txt" and "api.txt" there.  There are a few tutorials and such around if you look online.  It doesn't matter particularly which kernel version source you look at -- the last revision of "api.txt" was 2011 and "framebuffer.txt" a decade before that (so the interface is very stable).

Note that you can't use the framebuffer from within X.  If you want to do graphics stuff within X, you have to use at least [Xlib](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib-tutorial/), or a higher level library built on that.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define MAX_SCREEN_AREA 100
int Gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
char essq[MAX_SCREEN_AREA]={0}; // String variable to hold the escape sequence
sprintf(essq, "\033[%d;%df", y,x);
printf("%s", essq);
return 0;
}
```

Try this.

Comment: Clever. Requires an xterminal right? And those are rows and columns in the xterm?

Comment: @CharlieBurns No, it requires an ANSI terminal (which xterms are, but so is the VT console), since that's an ANSI escape sequence.  However, that `%df` should be `%dH` for this to work, I think, which will move the cursor but not actually print anything.

Comment: @goldilocks. Thanks. I'm really old so I think "xterm".

Comment: I don't think it's what OP had in mind, but it might work for him. He/she was probably thinking pixels on screen.

Comment: @CharlieBurns : 'xterm' is totally valid contemporary nomenclature IMO, lol, either for the literal `xterm` or more colloquially any X server based GUI terminal.  What I meant was it does *not* require an xterm (or X windows), it requires an ANSI compatible terminal, but it will work on an xterm since xterms are ANSI compatible.  Sort of like a trout is a fish: if you have a recipe which calls for fish, you can use a trout, but it does not require one.  It just requires some kind of fish.